# How to fix a memory allocation error in a base class?

Tags: c++, memory, object, unhandled-exception

I have made a program which contains two classes. Base class includes the pointer object of its derived class. I then initialize the pointer object in the constructor of base class.

My Compiler does not give me error during compilation, but the program crashes when console window appears, giving the error of `UNHANDLED EXCEPION BAD ALLOCATION` for the object of the derived class.  What should I do to fix it?

Here is the code:

```
class x;

class y
{
    private:

      x *objx; // here is the error
    ...........................

};

class x: public y
{
    ...........................
    ................
};

y::y()
{
     objx=new x(); // bad allocation and the program crashes

     // I have also tried this way by commenting objx=new x();

     *objx=0; // but still the program crashes.
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: What language is this?  You should tag it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Since invoking the constructor in a derived class will invoke the constructor in the parent class it looks like you will have a recursive construction problem going on there - which is probably causing the exception.

To avoid that you could move the "new x()" out of the constructor into its own function.

Comment: but then the compiler give error in the initialization of the data members of the derived class. What do i do now!

Answer (score 1):

As explained in another answer, you have an infinitely recursive construction problem. You might want to try setting the pointer to null in the constructor and create a method *init* that would make the actual object :

```
y::y()
{
     // *objx=0; // this is wrong, you don't want to dereference your pointer.
     objx = 0;   // this should work
}

void y::init()
{
     objx = new x();
}
```

Comment: i have tried it too. but the problem as i mentioned earlier is that, when i do it like this, the data members of the Parent class Y and derived class x remain uninitialized, i dont why!!

Comment: the error pops up to be
 Unhandled exception at 0x00401dd9 in pacman.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000020.
for all data members of class x and y

Comment: Are you sure you call init() after you have created the object y ? Y y; y.init();